# How to find cause of high memory usage in a complex C# based Windows service?

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, windows-services, .net-4.5, memory-profiling

I am having problems figuring out the source of a memory problem in a complex C# based Windows service. Unfortunately the problem does not occur all the time and I still don't exactly know the conditions which cause it to happen. Sometimes when I check the system ressources used by the service, it takes up multiple gigabytes of memory until the point where it throws OutOfMemory-exceptions everywhere because there isn't any memory left.

I have a paid version of .NET Memory Profiler available but so far it has been useless because the whole system becomes slow and unstable when the service uses too much memory so I cannot attach the memory profiler to the application.

The solution of the application consists of more than 30 individual projects and hundreds of thousands lines of code so there is no way for me to find the source of the problem by simply looking through the source code.

So far the only thing I was able to do is creating a memory dump (.dmp file) of the process while it was using a lot of memory. Is there a way to analyze this dump or anything else that would help me narrow down the source of this problem?

Comment: The .dmp file can be analyzed in visual studio. This is just like debugging the process. But it does not really show where the memory is used, but maybe you can get a hint what the process was doing. And you can try to increase logging, especially around things that may be using much memory (for example log the element count of suspicous lists etc).

Comment: I would expect most memory profilers to be able to import a dump file for further study. So I would check the documentation for your profiler.

Answer (score 1):

If you could identify some central methods in the main classes of your legacy projects and you have some kind of logging already in place, you could log the total memory (managed and unmanaged, if your application opens such resources) by calling

```
Process.GetCurrentProcess().PrivateMemorySize64
```

At least that would give you a feeling if the memory problem is "diffuse", e. g. by not release objects for garbage collection etc., if if the memory problem occurs just in certain use cases (jump in memory consumption, if a certain action happens). Then you could nail it down by more logging and investigating the corresponding code sections. Its tedious, but when you can not use code instrumentation as you have said, I find it effective. If you want to analyze a specific situation with a memory dump, you can use WinDbg for analyzing it, but that takes some effort for the first time to learn, and would be a separate topic (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/debugger-download-tools).